# How to stop game using SurfaceView

Tags: android, multithreading

When using Surface View to make a game, I have a problem. I have a `MainThread` class, and all my update functions are in the `run()` function. The condition is:

```
while(running){
    //do anything
}
```

I want to stop playing game and resume that by 2 menu items. In "stop item" I set  `thread.setRunning(false)` and in "resume item" I set `thread.setRunning(true)`, but it keeps running anyway!

After that, I tried to put a boolean inside the loop like this:

```
while(running){
    if(isPlaying == true){
        //do anything
    }
}
```

And if I want to stop, I set the boolean variable to false and true to resume. But that doesn't work either. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while(running){
    if(isPlaying == true){
        //do anything
    } else break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set false, the thread will end and never stop again, unless you create a new thread. Therefore, you need to add a new menu item to control "quit". The "running" is used to control "resume" and "pause". For example:

```
public class MainThread extends Thread{
    volatile boolean isQuit = false;
    volatile boolean running = false;
    Object lock = new Object();

    public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        this.running = running;
        synchronized (lock) {
            lock.notify();
        }
    }

    public void setQuit(boolean isQuit) {
        this.isQuit = isQuit;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.run();

        while (!isQuit) {
            if (!running) {
                System.out.println("pause ganme");
                synchronized (lock) {
                    try {
                        lock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        System.out.println(e);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                // continue game
                System.out.println("running ganme");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("quit ganme");
    }

    public void quit() {
        isQuit = true;
        running = false;
        synchronized (lock) {
            lock.notify();
        }
    }
}
```